# AFNetworking and synchronous request to fulfil online registration process

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, afnetworking

I am using AFNetworking and I've read that synchronous responses are discouraged. yet I need to check whether a user already exist in the online database before the person can go to the next stage of the app. Yes, a typical registration process.

My code as it stands it returns NO because is asynchronous. I need to find a way to check for the success call and return `YES` or `NO` depending on this callback.

Could anyone point me in the right direction of how to write an app that waits for the success call so that I know that the user has not been set?

```
-(BOOL)doesTheUserExistAlreadyOnServer:(NSString *)parsedEmail
{
    BOOL *methodResponse = NO;

    AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.myurl.co.uk/"]];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient requestWithMethod:@"POST"
                                                            path:@"http://www.myurl.co.uk/igym.php"
                                                      parameters:@{@"myvar2":@"piggy"}];
    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
    [httpClient registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFHTTPRequestOperation class]];
    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        // Print the response body in text

      //  NSLog(@"Response: %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
        if ([[[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] isEqualToString:@"piggy"]) {
            __block methodResponse = YES;
            NSLog(@"%@",[[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
        }
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];
    [operation start];

    return (BOOL)methodResponse;

}
```

**EDIT:**

I solved the problem using the following logic.

The user clicks on the registration button. The main method does all the preliminary non-web checks, then calls the `[self doesTheUserExistAlreadyOnServer:_email.text];`

that method code is now

```
-(void)doesTheUserExistAlreadyOnServer:(NSString *)parsedEmail
{ 
    if(![_spinner isAnimating])
    {
        [_spinner startAnimating];
    }

    __block RegistrationViewController* me = self;
    AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.myurl.co.uk/"]];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient requestWithMethod:@"POST"
                                                            path:@"http://www.myurl.co.uk/igym.php"
                                                      parameters:@{@"myvar2":@"piggy"}];
    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
    [httpClient registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFHTTPRequestOperation class]];
    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        // Print the response body in text

        if ([[[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] isEqualToString:@"piggy"]) {

            NSLog(@"%@",[[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
            [me registrationPartTwo:YES];
        } else
        {
            [me registrationPartTwo:NO];
        }
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];

    [operation start];

}
```

Then once that block/callback is successful it calls

```
-(void)registrationPartTwo:(BOOL)doesItExistOnServer
{
    [_spinner stopAnimating];
    NSString *emailAlreadyInUseMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"This email is already in use"];
    if (doesItExistOnServer)
    {
        self.screenMsg.text = emailAlreadyInUseMessage;
//here more code to send the user the the next step
    }
}
```

basically i solved this using a 2method registration process dependant upon callback, dont know if thats the best or most efficient way. but thats the way i could solve it on my own.

Answer (score 0):

Use a delegate callback to notify when the operation completes. If needed, before starting the operation, put up an `UIActivityIndicatorView` (the spinner) to prevent the user from interacting with the app.

Comment: I am pretty new to this. Could you provide an example or link to an example please?